# SQL Server PDF Full-Text Search not working on FileStream PDF File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, filestream

I cannot get the Full-Text search to work on PDF files I am loading into my SQL Db via FileStream.

Version: SQL Server 2008 R2 (Developer Edition - doing proof of concept)
OS: Windows 7

Steps I have taken.

- Installed the Adobe iFilter
- Made sure SQL Server full Text Daemon service is running
- Added the environment path to the Adobe PDF Filter bin directory
- Ran the below scripts to setup the new iFilter and make sure it is
  active

  ```
  EXEC sp_fulltext_service @action='load_os_resources', @value=1; -- update os resources 
  EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'verify_signature', 0 -- don't verify signatures
  EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages'; -- update language list
  EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts'; -- restart daemon  
  EXEC sp_help_fulltext_system_components 'filter'; -- view active filters
  ```
- Created the full-text index on the FileStream table I wanted to index

  ```
  CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX on local.FILE_REPOSITORY
  (DOCUMENT TYPE COLUMN FILE_EXTENSION)
  Key Index PK_File_Repository ON 
  (FileSearchCat, FILEGROUP [PRIMARY]);
  GO
  ```
- Rebuilt Catalog

  ```
  ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG FileSearchCatREBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY=OFF;
  ```
- Ran a query to see if the index is working

  ```
  select * 
  from local.FILE_REPOSITORYwhere freetext(DOCUMENT, '25678')
  ```

Doesn't return any results for PDF, but works fine for word (docx)?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out....I needed to run these steps:

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_service @action='load_os_resources', @value=1; -- update os resources 
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'verify_signature', 0 -- don't verify signatures 
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages'; -- update language list 
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts'; -- restart daemon 
EXEC sp_help_fulltext_system_components 'filter'; -- view active filters
```

But Also needed to run this!!!!

```
reconfigure with override
```

Comment: Have you tested the above solution on tables that have binary data stored in column of type Image? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I also rebuild the full text catalog after executing your commands. ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG ftCatalog REBUILD.