# Is Adobe iFilter 11.0 compatible with SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, pdf, sql-server-2014, ifilter

we are using PDF iFilter 11.0 from Adobe for full text searching of PDF contents stored in SQL Server DB.
Everything works as expected if we use the SQL Server release 2005, 2008 & 2012.
We have now tested the latest SQL Server release 2014 and see that our SQL query that uses the full text index returns no rows.
We tried a lot to be sure that the iFilter is correctly installed - however the SQL query does not return the expected result set.

Question: Is someone successfully using Adobe iFilter 11.0 64bit with SQL Server 2014?
If so, how did you install the iFilter?

Comment: We did some more investigations. It looks as Adobe iFilter 11.0 64bit does not work also with SQL Server 2008 and 2012(?).

Is someone successfully using  Adobe iFilter 11.0 64bit with Sql Server 2008 or 2012?

Comment: It might be late but... I'm using Adobe PDF iFilter 11 for 64-bit on SQL Server 2008 R2. Did you get it working on SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Please check this answer. It worked for me on SQL 2014 with iFilter 11 64bit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690921/sql-server-pdf-full-text-search-not-working-on-filestream-pdf-file?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In the video from the link below you can see how this guy runs Adobe iFilter 11 64-bits on SQL Server 2014.

http://dba-presents.com/index.php/databases/sql-server/48-full-text-search-with-pdf-documents-in-sql-server-2014

I tried to do it like him several times without any success. The only difference is that I'm using newer sql server 2014 version, than the one from the video. I guess that this is an issue only with the latest 2014 versions.

Finally I was able to enable full text search on my sql server 2014 with iFilter version 9. Probably this issue doesn't exists in version 9. You can download version 9 from ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/9.x/